# Tools > Import Wordpress does not allow XML file over 2 MB

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How do I change the Import Wordpress limit of 2 MB for uploading an XML file?  Searched everywhere - most people talk about increasing limits in php.ini or .htaccess.  Both are unrelated to this issue, and do nothing to the screen which looks like this in Wordpress 3.8.1:

[image]

This video is the only apparent fix: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZsXQ1KrObU

It shows exactly my problem, and how to solve it.  Unfortunately - it doesn't change anything in WP 3.8.1. I'm amazed this hasn't been addressed.

Comment: but this is exactly php limit, not from wp.

Comment: @MichalS You would think so. But phpinfo shows my upload_max_filesize as 64M, after I modified php.ini. The Import Wordpress screen still shows "Maximum size: 2 MB".

Comment: where is your php.ini in local directory?

Comment: Yeah it is. Just tried copying it to /wp-admin, and that solved it!

Comment: glad my help was useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. Create a php.ini file in the /wp-admin directory with the following code:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

It won't work if the file is in the root directory.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to try asking your hosting provider they may have set the upload limit at 2mb and can change it quite easily